# Implement reinforcement learning with pure tensor style (without feeding) in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I am having problems implementing reinforcement learning (RL) algorithms with pure tensor style in tensorflow. The idea comes from the implementation of Deepmind's [IMPALA](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.01561). The code is written in a pure tensor style without fetches and feeds. The authors use tf.py_func() to convert the emulator into tensorflow ops. Then the worker ops put data to tf.queue and the learner pull training data from tf.contrib.staging.StagingArea to calculate loss functions and the optimizer. Finally, a single fetch of the optimizer runs all algorithm. I want to convert the code to other RL algorithms. So as an exercise, I am trying to train with gym and I am trying policy gradient (PG) and proximal policy optimization (PPO). However, I have very bad results in last few weeks and need someone's help.

My code to run the gym's games in my [repo](https://github.com/fredericgo/ppo_pure_tensor).

I am not sure if I get right at PG algorithm. The result of PG for "CartPole-v0". It finally converges to score of 200. But the result of PG for "LunarLander-v2" looks problematic. The algorithm first learns something, but after a while the episodic return dropped drastically down to a wrong place and never come back. But my PPO does not learn anything at all. ([see pictures here](https://github.com/fredericgo/ppo_pure_tensor/tree/master/images))

My implementations are here: [PG](https://github.com/fredericgo/ppo_pure_tensor/blob/master/pg_discrete.py), and [PPO](https://github.com/fredericgo/ppo_pure_tensor/blob/master/ppo_discrete.py).

Please help me find out what goes wrong with my code? The outcome of pure-tensor code is supposed to match those of the conventional ones. As a reference, I also provide these RL algorithms using conventional tensorflow fetches and feeds here: [PG conventional](https://github.com/fredericgo/ppo_pure_tensor/blob/master/conventional/pg.py) and [PPO conventional](https://github.com/fredericgo/ppo_pure_tensor/blob/master/conventional/ppo.py).

Comment: It's kind of a big thing to ask people to do a code review to debug your code. Perhaps you could narrow down the scope by creating a minimal example where the two approaches diverge.

Comment: @Kris, thank you. It's almost one week after I posted this question. Now I made a little bit progress. I will edit the question and simplify it very soon.